# Get data for Last day of each week

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I want to get the data of last day of each week (Sunday). I am using below query which gives me latest row for each day, how can I modify it to get data for only last day of each week?

```
WITH
  Pointintime AS (
   SELECT
     *
   , "row_number"() OVER (PARTITION BY ResourceId, ControlId, itcfid, "date_format"(Datetime, '%Y'), "date_format"(Datetime, '%j') ORDER BY DateTime DESC) rn
   FROM
     employee
) 
SELECT *
FROM
  Pointintime 
WHERE (rn = 1)
```

Below is some sample data of last week (Mon-Sun), I want to only get latest row of Sunday (Last day of the week). This has to be done for a given year.

```
Input
ITCFID  ControlId   ResourceId  DateTime
P05.01.03   CloudFront.1    AWS:::Acount:1111111111111  12/19/2021 5:00 PM  
P05.01.03   CloudFront.1    AWS:::Acount:1111111111111  12/19/2021 06:01 AM 
P05.01.03   CloudFront.1    AWS:::Acount:1111111111111  12/18/2021 5:00 PM  
P05.01.03   CloudFront.1    AWS:::Acount:1111111111111  12/18/2021 06:01 AM 
P05.01.03   CloudFront.1    AWS:::Acount:1111111111111  12/17/2021 5:00 PM  
P05.01.03   CloudFront.1    AWS:::Acount:1111111111111  12/17/2021 06:01 AM 
P05.01.03   CloudFront.1    AWS:::Acount:1111111111111  12/16/2021 5:00 PM  
P05.01.03   CloudFront.1    AWS:::Acount:1111111111111  12/16/2021 06:01 AM 
P05.01.03   CloudFront.1    AWS:::Acount:1111111111111  12/15/2021 5:00 PM  
P05.01.03   CloudFront.1    AWS:::Acount:1111111111111  12/15/2021 06:01 AM 
P05.01.03   CloudFront.1    AWS:::Acount:1111111111111  12/14/2021 5:00 PM  
P05.01.03   CloudFront.1    AWS:::Acount:1111111111111  12/14/2021 06:01 AM 
P05.01.03   CloudFront.1    AWS:::Acount:1111111111111  12/13/2021 5:00 PM  
P05.01.03   CloudFront.1    AWS:::Acount:1111111111111  12/13/2021 06:01 AM

Output
ITCFID  ControlId   ResourceId  DateTime
P05.01.03   CloudFront.1    AWS:::Acount:1111111111111  12/19/2021 5:00 PM
```

For a particular ITCFID -> There can be multiple Control ID and Control ID can have multiple Resource ID. I want to get for a particular itcfid -> Unique Control ID -> Unique ResourceID -> Get last row for each itcfid of that week.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including sample data and desired results.

Comment: Added as requested

Comment: In your where clause add `datename(day,MyDate) = 'Sunday'` using the appropriate format for your database (for which you will have to check the documentation).

Comment: How you will do it in SQL ?

Comment: That is SQL, just for SQL Server (`where datename(day,MyDate) = 'Sunday'`), you need to look up the docs for your database. And you aren't familiar with a `where` clause I highly recommend taking a few tutorials.

Comment: It seems amazon-athena (if that is what you are using) has a day_of_week function you can use like where day_of_week(MyDate)=7 (7 is Sunday according to ISO8601)